# How to compile a dart file inside a dart file

Tags: dart

So i am making an programming language in dart. So I don't know how to compile a dart file inside a dart file without running an dart compile exe command. Here is my code

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(List<String> args) async {
  String contents = new File(args[0]).readAsStringSync();
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  var fileCopy = File(args[0].replaceAll('.idk', '.dart')).writeAsStringSync(contents);
  Process.runSync('dart compile exe ${args[0].replaceAll(".idk", ".dart")}',[]).stdout.toString();
  Process.runSync('del ${args[0].replaceAll(".idk", ".dart")}', []).stdout.toString();
  print("${args[0]} has compiled");
}
```

How can i compile a dart file without running an command since requires people to have the full file path. But now there is another issue when trying to compile an .idk file.

```
ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified.

  Command: "dart compile exe F:\code_work\darting\something.dart"
#0      _ProcessImpl._runAndWait (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:487)
#1      _runNonInteractiveProcessSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:632)        
#2      Process.runSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:68)
#3      main (file:///f:/code_work/darting/test.dart:7)
#4      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192)
```

How can i fix or atleast make this work again?

Comment: Why do you need to compile a Dart file from within Dart? What does that have to do with making a programming language?

Comment: I am making a compiler for the language i am making and i don't want to make it an interpreter language. A programming language requires a compiler or interpreter

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why you want to compile Dart in particular - Are you transpiling your own language to Dart, and then compiling the generated Dart code?

Comment: At any rate, I did find why you got that error and posted an answer - Good luck with the compiler!

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the environment of the spawned process doesn't include your usual `PATH` environment variable, so it doesn't know where to look for the `dart` command.

You can fix this by setting `runInShell` to `true`. That way, the process will run as if it were invoked in the shell, with the same environment variables.

```dart
Process.runSync(
  'dart compile exe ${args[0].replaceAll(".idk", ".dart")}', 
  [],
  runInShell: true,
)
    .stdout.toString();
```